# Reversed order of Facebook Timeline

Tags: facebook, facebook-timeline

Is there *any* way to have Facebook Page's Timeline in reversed order, i.e. with first events at top and going all down to the newest event at the bottom?

I've searched the Internet for many queries about this, but found nothing of good quality. Most entries found were too old (before changes to Timeline, Facebook introduced recently) or were off-topic. I'm new to Facebook, but I think I checked most promising settings and also found nothing.

So, is this simple task possible at all in Facebook?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, this isn't possible with Facebook natively. You will need to use the API to build this (which is outside the scope of this site)